# US MAP (Highchart) mouseover tooltip from another div

Tags: react-highcharts

I am having trouble with the mouseover tooltip while working on the map below.
Website address: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/data-class-two-ranges

On the same page as my US map rendering, I have a table listing all the states in the US.

Problem: Just as needed, a tooltip will appear on the map chart when the user hovers their mouse over the state table (State name).

need tooltip show over the map when user mouseover the state listing table(State Name)

Answer (score 0):

I have got solutions from Highcharts Team.
Really Thank you @Jakub

but i am still struggling for this so looking solutions in react Highcharts library.

Demo in JavaScript: "https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5sk2hdbz/"

need solution in react(Highcharts).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).